# simple web scraper very slow

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm fairly new to python and web-scraping in general. The code below works but it seems to be awfully slow for the amount of information its actually going through. Is there any way to easily cut down on execution time. I'm not sure but it does seem like I have typed out more/made it more difficult then I actually needed to, any help would be appreciated.

Currently the code starts at the sitemap then iterates through a list of additional sitemaps. Within the new sitemaps it pulls data information to construct a url for the json data of a webpage. From the json data I pull an xml link that I use to search for a string. If the string is found it appends it to a text file.

```
#global variable
start = 'https://www.govinfo.gov/wssearch/getContentDetail?packageId='
dash = '-'
urlSitemap="https://www.govinfo.gov/sitemap/PLAW_sitemap_index.xml"

old_xml=requests.get(urlSitemap)
print (old_xml)
new_xml= io.BytesIO(old_xml.content).read()
final_xml=BeautifulSoup(new_xml)
linkToBeFound = final_xml.findAll('loc')
for loc in linkToBeFound:
    urlPLmap=loc.text
    old_xmlPLmap=requests.get(urlPLmap)
    print(old_xmlPLmap)
    new_xmlPLmap= io.BytesIO(old_xmlPLmap.content).read()
    final_xmlPLmap=BeautifulSoup(new_xmlPLmap)
    linkToBeFound2 = final_xmlPLmap.findAll('loc')
    for pls in linkToBeFound2:
        argh = pls.text.find('PLAW')
        theWanted = pls.text[argh:]
        thisShallWork =eval(requests.get(start + theWanted).text)
        print(requests.get(start + theWanted))
        dict1 = (thisShallWork['download'])
        finaldict = (dict1['modslink'])[2:]
        print(finaldict)
        url2='https://' + finaldict
        try:    
            old_xml4=requests.get(url2)
            print(old_xml4)
            new_xml4= io.BytesIO(old_xml4.content).read()
            final_xml4=BeautifulSoup(new_xml4)
            references = final_xml4.findAll('identifier',{'type': 'Statute citation'})
            for sec in references: 
                if sec.text == "106 Stat. 4845":
                    Print(dash * 20)
                    print(sec.text)
                    Print(dash * 20)
                    sec313 = open('sec313info.txt','a')
                    sec313.write("\n")
                    sec313.write(pls.text + '\n')
                    sec313.close()
        except:
            print('error at: ' + url2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why i spent so long on this, but i did. Your code was really hard to look through. So i started with that, I broke it up into 2 parts, getting the links from the sitemaps, then the other stuff. I broke out a few bits into separate functions too.
This is checking about 2 urls per second on my machine which seems about right.
How this is better (you can argue with me about this part).

- Don't have to reopen and close the output file after each write
- Removed a fair bit of unneeded code
- gave your variables better names (this does not improve speed in any way but please do this especially if you are asking for help with it)
- Really the main thing... once you break it all up it becomes fairly clear that whats slowing you down is waiting on the requests which is pretty standard for web-scraping, you can look into multi threading to avoid the wait. Once you get into multi threading, the benefit of breaking up your code will likely also become much more evident.

```
# returns sitemap links
def get_links(s):
    old_xml = requests.get(s)
    new_xml = old_xml.text
    final_xml = BeautifulSoup(new_xml, "lxml")
    return final_xml.findAll('loc')

# gets the final url from your middle url and looks through it for the thing you are looking for
def scrapey(link):
    link_id = link[link.find("PLAW"):]
    r = requests.get('https://www.govinfo.gov/wssearch/getContentDetail?packageId={}'.format(link_id))
    print(r.url)
    try:
        r = requests.get("https://{}".format(r.json()["download"]["modslink"][2:]))
        print(r.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        references = soup.findAll('identifier', {'type': 'Statute citation'})
        for ref in references:
            if ref.text == "106 Stat. 4845":
                return r.url
        else:
            return False
    except:
        print("bah" + r.url)
        return False


sitemap_links_el = get_links("https://www.govinfo.gov/sitemap/PLAW_sitemap_index.xml")
sitemap_links = map(lambda x: x.text, sitemap_links_el)
nlinks_el = map(get_links, sitemap_links)
links = [num.text for elem in nlinks_el for num in elem]



with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
    for link in links:
        url = scrapey(link)
        if url is False:
            print("no find")
        else:
            print("found on: {}".format(url))
            f.write("{}\n".format(url))
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't increase scrape time a ton but now the code is actually workable. I hope to get better haha

Comment: breaking it up is the way to get better, I am still in that stage myself and have to rewrite/structure my own code quite often. Good luck, and if speed is a big consideration look into multi threading. You can get really really good performance improvements particularly with web-scraping.